# How can I make a template compatible with multiple LaTeX distributions (in different versions)?

Tags: latex3, texlive-2019

I am working on a template where we are using the function `\text_purify:n`

[image]

but this function was only added 2020-03-05 and hence is not part of TeXlive 2019. The problem is, that this template shall also run on a vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (without manual installation of TeXlive), only via available packages.

No assume I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyPurifyFunction}{m}{\text_purify:n #1}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \MyPurifyFunction{Test}
\end{document}
```

`\usepackage{expl3,xparse}` is needed with TeXlive 2019, but how can I make the `\NewDocumentCommand{\MyPurifyFunction}{m}{\text_purify:n #1}` compilable? It would be fine for me to just say:

```
\if_text_purify_not_available
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyPurifyFunction}{m}{#1}
```

So basically letting `\MyPurifyFunction` do nothing, but how can I implement the `\if_text_purify_not_available` part?

Comment: expl3 has various `\cs_if_exist_XXX` tests, check interface3.pdf. In standard latex you can use `\@ifundefined`.

Comment: You can also use `\ifdefined` from plain TeX.

Comment: If you choose `\@ifundefined`, you will have to enclose it in `\makeatletter` & `\makeatother` pair unless you are writing in a .cls or .sty file.

Comment: @Niranjan the OP is obvioulsy writing L3 programming layer so suggesting a 2e function is only complicating it for  him I would say. But if we speaking of  2e, that also has \IfFormatAtLeastTF which may help to group blocks of missing definitions and being CamelCase works anywhere

Comment: Thanks @FrankMittelbach, but the 2e-method was recommended by Ulrike. I just added the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` part and since various ways of checking if something is defined or not were being suggested I mentioned the `\ifdefined` too, but nothing particularly against the L3 layer was meant by it.

Comment: Thank you all, based on your comments, I posted an answer that is how I am doing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there are multiple ways to check if the macro exists, for LaTeX3, the most suitable solution is:

`\NewDocumentCommand{\MyPurifyFunction}{m}{\cs_if_exist:NTF \text_purify:n {\text_purify:n #1}{#1}}`